# Calculate intersections from three formulas with unknown elements

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have some issues understanding an exercise I'm trying to work out:

"The demand of a good is prescribed by the equation q = 4 - 2p. The cost function equals C(q) = q and the revenue is equal to R(q) = pq. Determine the break-even points."

I am clueless on how to imagine the Cost function (I know it's constant). How would I approach solving this question? From the answers I see the intersections are (p,q) (2,0) and (1,2). I'm sorry if this is a totally amateur question, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

For break even you want revenue to be the same as cost.

$$ pq=q \implies q(p-1)=0 $$

Thus $p=1$ or $q=0$

For $p=1$ we can also find $$ q=p(4-2p)=2$$

Or you can have $$q=0, p=2$$ which does not make sense in real world.